# Copy objects with collections in scala

Tags: scala

I want to clean fields of some objects which are part of collections(setting to None). Below is the class hierarchy and their structures

```
final case class OrderItem(
                                 simpleSku: String,
                                 merchant: Option[String])
final case class OrderItemGroup(id: String,
                                    items: Seq[OrderItem],
                                    fType: Option[String])
final case class OrderRequest(groups: Seq[OrderItemGroup])

val orderItem1 = OrderItem("simple1",Some("merchant1"))
val salesOrderItem2 = OrderItem("simple2",Some("merchant2"))
val salesOrderItem3 = OrderItem("simple3",Some("merchant3"))
val c1 = OrderItemGroup("id1",Seq(orderItem1,salesOrderItem3),Some("fulfillmentA"))
val c2 = OrderItemGroup("id2",Seq(orderItem1,salesOrderItem2),Some("fulfillmentB"))
val o = OrderRequest(Seq(c1,c2))
```

I basically want to clean fields merchant and fType and come up with the following code but its multiplying inner items. How can this be done with .copy approach?

```
def clearFields (orderRequest:OrderRequest) :OrderRequest = {
  val items = orderRequest.groups.flatMap(x => x.items)
  println("items" + items)
  val groups = orderRequest.groups
  val r = orderRequest.copy(groups = groups.map(_.copy(fType = None, items = items.map(_.copy(merchant = None)))))
  r
}
```

Comment: What's the question? You're already doing this using `.copy`.

Comment: Question is how to do it in a correct way. The way I show flattening all items then which results in 4 items in each goup. however it should be 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Monocle](http://julien-truffaut.github.io/Monocle/) is helpful when we have to copy such nested structures, for example,

```
import monocle.Traversal
import monocle.macros.GenLens
import cats.implicits._ 

val cleanMerchant = GenLens[OrderItem](_.merchant).set(None)
val cleanFType = GenLens[OrderItemGroup](_.fType).set(None)
val cleanGroupItems = Traversal.fromTraverse[List, OrderItemGroup].modify(g => g.copy(items = g.items.map(cleanMerchant)))

OrderRequest(cleanGroupItems(o.groups.toList).map(cleanFType))
```

outputs

```
OrderRequest(List(OrderItemGroup(id1,List(OrderItem(simple1,None), OrderItem(simple3,None)),None), OrderItemGroup(id2,List(OrderItem(simple1,None), OrderItem(simple2,None)),None)))
```

To clean it using vanilla Scala try

```
def cleanOrderItemGroup(group: OrderItemGroup): OrderItemGroup = {
  val items = group.items
  val cleanItems = items.map(cleanOrderItem)
  group.copy(items = cleanItems, fType = None)
}

def cleanOrderItem(item: OrderItem): OrderItem = {
  item.copy(merchant = None)
}

OrderRequest(o.groups.map(cleanOrderItemGroup))
```

which again outputs

```
OrderRequest(List(OrderItemGroup(id1,List(OrderItem(simple1,None), OrderItem(simple3,None)),None), OrderItemGroup(id2,List(OrderItem(simple1,None), OrderItem(simple2,None)),None)))
```

Comment: output is correct. However, I am wondering how to do that using standard scala libraries?

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot.